# Use of a VPN to access website when not expressly prohibited in the terms and conditions of the licence/account

Tags: terms-of-service

Often no mention, direct or indirect, is made regarding the use VPNs, proxy servers, or other online privacy measures whilst accessing the websites of certain online bookmakers.

However, in the forums of these websites and and sometimes in other information on the same website or even obtained from their customer services representatives etc. it is sometimes claimed that the use of such privacy measures is prohibited for that website.

Must such a prohibition be expressly stated in the Terms and Conditions of the agreement when creating the account in order for such a company to have legal grounds to consider that an account holder accessing the website when using such a privacy device constitutes violation of the account terms and conditions and, particularly, as grounds to withhold funds in the user's account balance / block withdrawals or deposits?